# kafka-node: consumer group members/instances

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Environment

1. Node version: latest
2. Kafka-node version: 2.6.1
3. Kafka version: latest

Hi, there is a way to know or get Consumer Group members/consumers/instances?
i know there is an option in Kafka itself ('GroupMembers') but i need it in node.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka-node exposes an Admin API that has a [`describeGroups()`](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node#describegroupsconsumergroups-cb) method.

For example:

```js
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient();
const admin = new kafka.Admin(client);
admin.describeGroups(['my-consumer-group'], (err, res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 1));
});
```

You can also use Kafka-node Admin API to [list groups](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node#listgroupscb).